# Compound (double) inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

Just want to understand why we have a specific approach to solving double inequalities for example separating the statement $-6 < 2x-4 < 12$ into two components. Working left two sides first and then the right two sides etc.

What is troubling me is this. The following statement is true.

$1 < 2 < 3$

In words, 3 is greater than 2 which is greater than 1. Let x = 2 therefore:

(x-1) < x < (x+1)

The standard approach doesn't work anymore (I think) so if you work from left hand side,

x - 1 < x

x - x < 1

and whilst 0 is less than 1 which is true, there is no x variable to work with. Shouldn't this somehow return something like x > (0, 1, or any number less than 2) and x < (10, 20, or any number greater than 2)?

Why is that?
Or what am I doing wrong?

Thank You.

Comment: Can you explain what you are doing on both sides?

Comment: When you eliminate a variable... well, you eliminate a variable.  $x-x < 1$.  What don't you understand about that?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Sorry for the confusion caused.

If I told you x was equals to 2, $(x-1) < x < (x+1)$ would become $1 < 2 < 3$ which is true. But what if I didn't tell you x was equals to 2, how would you find out what x might equal to just by looking at $(x-1) < x < (x+1)$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are fundamentally misinterpreting how you are using variables in your example. In order to explain why, you must first understand what you are claiming. To say

> Shouldn't this somehow return something like x > (0, 1, or any number less than 2) and x < (10, 20, or any number greater than 2)?

is the same as saying

$x > 0, 1, 1.5, 1.9, 1.99, ...$
and
$x < 100, 10, 5, 2.5, 2.1, 2.01, ...$

We can equivalently say that $x \geq 2$ and $x \leq 2$. When you take these two inequalities together, you get $x = 2$.

However, $x-1 < x < x+1$ is a different claim altogether. Yes, $x = 2$ is one solution to this set of inequalities, but there are infinitely many other solutions. For example, if $x = 7$, then $6<7<8$.

Therefore, you can play around with the inequalities, but you are not going to find the single solution $x = 2$ because the inequalities have more solutions, infinitely more in fact.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I should have experimented with a range of values to see how the results might differ.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in your case, you assumed 
$(x-1) < x < (x+1)$ 
is true when $x=2$, but you also have to consider that $(x-1) < x < (x+1)$ is true for all real values of $x$, therefore it has no definite value which you can 'return' to.

You can try: 
$x=1: 0 < 1 < 2$

$x=100: 99 < 100 < 101$ and the list goes on

And, as a side note, we can see that the $x$'s cancel each other out, just like in an equation. For example, in
$x + y = x + 3$

$x$ can take on any value and the equation will remain solvable over $y$.

So: $(x-1) < x < (x+1) \rightarrow  -1 < 0 < 1$

Comment: I really appreciate your response. And yes, you are right in saying that any real value of x would satisfy the statement $(x−1)<x<(x+1)$.

Thanks a lot.